# joomla how to create a custom link

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have set mod_rewrite in joomla so I can use link like http://www.mysite.com/home, http://www.mysite.com/contact where home and contact are link aliases.
All of this link are part of menu, but I'm intersted in create link that will be never displayed in any menu, how can do that?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways it can be done. The quick and easy way is to make a hidden menu just for creating links. Simply create a new menu and don't put it in a module. You can add all the menu items you want without having to display them anywhere and you get nice clean URLs.

You can also get the URL of an article that does not have a menu item, but it gets pretty long to use. The URL of an article will be something like -

domain.com/parent menu item alias/item alias.html

It will use the alias from what ever menu item it is inheriting the itemID from az part of the URL. I generally use the first method to avoid the long URLs.

Comment: Thank you man.

For the rest: To create a menu that doesn't belong to a module just leave blank the field "Module title" in "New Menu" form.

Comment: Good point, the Module Title field is optional and if left blank the menu will not display on the site. I'll add that to my answers in the future, I always forget that.